# Bulk unbind an XML tag

Tags: html, xml, search, replace, unbind

I need to perform a bulk unbind of tags from about 1000 html files, where I need to remove all P tags which are contained within an LI item:

```
<div>
  <img src="a.png" />
</div>
<ul>
   <li>
      <p>list item 1</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p>list item 2</p>
   </li>
</ul>
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      <p>list item 1</p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p>list item 2</p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

After the unbind is performed, then the list items in all files display like this:

```
<div>
  <img src="a.png" />
</div>
<ul>
   <li>
      list item 1
   </li>
   <li>
      list item 2
   </li>
</ul>
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
   <li>
      list item 1
   </li>
   <li>
      list item 2
   </li>
</ul>
```

Notice how only the P tags within the LI are removed.
The unbind operation needs to be done at source (on the html files test), and not while rendering.
What is the best way to perform this bulk unbind please?

Comment: You want to unbind <p> tags on page load or you want to parse html file as xml and unbind tags?

Comment: Not on page load, but unbind them directly from source.

Comment: Then you can use parse html as xml and remove tags. You can do this with Java. If size of your html files bigger then use Java SAX parser else you can use Java DOM Parser